# limit point compact metric space is totally bounded

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

If $(X,d)$ is a compact metric space, proving that it is totally bounded is easier. however, how is it different when it $(X,d)$ is a limit point compact metric space?

Answer (score 5):

Suppose $(X,d)$ is limit point compact.
Then $(X,d)$ is totally bounded:

Suppose not. Then there is some $r>0$ such that $X$ cannot be covered by finitely many $r$-balls.
Pick $x_1 \in X$, and having chosen $x_n$ we pick $x_{n+1} \notin \cup_{i \le n} B(x_i, r)$, which can be done by this assumption.

This defines a sequence $(x_n)_{n \ge 1}$ in $X$ such that $$\text{(1) } \forall n \ge 1: \forall i < n: d(x_n, x_i) \ge r$$

But $A = \{x_n: n \ge 1\}$ has a limit point $p$, and so we can pick $x_{n_1} \neq x_{n_2}$ both in $B(p, \frac{r}{2})$ (the ball intersects the set $A$ in infinitely many points, even), but then $D(x_{n_1}, x_{n_2}) < r$ by the triangle inequality and this contradicts the distance property (1) from before. This contradiction shows that $(X,d)$ must be totally bounded.

Note that almost the same proof will show it for sequential compactness as well: a convergent subsequence must also cluster at the limit.

Comment: +1 from me  (in 1 hour because i exceeded  the voting limit...:P)..i have not thought or seen a proof that limit point compactness implies total boundeness directly